# Can one switch between output_notebook and output_file within an IPython notebook session with Bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm wondering if it is possible to generate static HTML output and inline plots using Bokeh in the same IPython notebook. What I am currently seeing is that once I either call `output_notebook()` or `output_file("myfile.html")` I am stuck using that output modality. For example, if I initially use `output_notebook`, subsequently calling `output_file` does not create an output file.

Comment: One correction: It seems that I can initially use `output_file` followed by `output_notebook`, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`reset_output()` before the next `output_notebook` or `output_file` call works at least in version 0.10.0 .

```python
# cell 1
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook, output_file, reset_output
p = figure(width=300, height=300)
p.line(range(5), range(5))
output_notebook()
show(p)

# cell 2
reset_output()
output_file('foo.html')
show(p)

# cell 3
reset_output()
output_notebook()
show(p)
```

First and third show in notebook, second shows in browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static HTML using the following code (adapted from example [here](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html)):

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.resources import CDN
from bokeh.embed import file_html

plot = figure()
plot.circle([1,2], [3,4])

html = file_html(plot, CDN, "my plot")

with open('test.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html)
```

This works no trouble in conjunction with `output_notebook()`

Comment: I have a similar situation, but my plots are created in a loop. Is it possible to append each plot to create a single html file with all of them on it?

Comment: Sorry for the overlook. I was thinking way to hard about that one. For reference you simply change the 'w' to 'a' just like with any file.